# if we use view in slow load of OLDB destination of data flow task of SSIS and any records in error then whole batch went into error tables

Tags: sql, ssis, ssis-2012

Using view in slow load of OLDB destination of SSIS , if any one records have  error then all batch went into error table  but we used table in slow load of OLDB destination  then only that error records went into error table.

We did not get why in case of using view all batch records went into error .

We did POC on it by using table in slow load of OLDB destination  and its working as per our requirement that means only error records went into error table.